# Can't boot XP after Ubuntu Installation, how to fix?

Tags: installation, grub2, windows

I installed Ubuntu and after the installation, i can't boot to XP. When i choose XP from the Grub menu, I got black screen for like 30 sec, and then it returns to the Grub menu.

Thanks!

Comment: Try booting ubuntu then type the command 'sudo update-grub' in the terminal to reconfigure grub2.

Comment: didn't help... other sulotion?

Comment: @yinon - the way that you bump the question is to reedit it with further information to move it up the activity list.  If it is important to you, then you can also raise a bounty on the question.

Comment: Did you press the wrong button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot into a live CD and run this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Install Use the Advanced options

To start using `gksudo boot-repair`

[image]

[image]

[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: I have no "MBR options" http://up353.siz.co.il/up2/iqym3ndxoytj.png  please help! and thanks!

Comment: @yinon there is a `Restore MBR` checkbox in the `Main options` tab. You need to click that in order to enable the `MBR options`. Not sure if the information is still needed, just mentioning.