# After installing, Ubuntu does not start unless LiveUSB is inserted and defaults to 7

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have a laptop with Windows 7. I installed ubuntu through USB. After restarting,, however, nothing happens. 7 automatically loads without showing the OS selection screen. But when I insert the live USB, the screen that lets me select Ubuntu shows up and I can access the Ubuntu OS installed on the hard drive. I'm new to this, but is this an instance where I should use [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)? And are there any specific instructions for it that I should be aware of? Thanks!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/115934/46312 should fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed the grub-menu not good. (on the wrong partition).  You can easily try to repair it with the boot-repair cd.  Follow the instructions.  It is safe.  In most of the cases it will make a proposition at his own.